# JSON to MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, websocket

I need to instert all response from a Websocket Cilent to a MySQL Database. 
Unfortunately, I did not find anything on the internet that could help me.
My code so far:

```
    def to_db(self):
    cur = self.db.cursor()
    db = self.db
    while True:
        data = self.ws.recv()
        print(data)
        sql = f"INSERT INTO `db`.`test` (`output`) VALUES ({data});"
        cur.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

When I run the scripts I get the following error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"event":"info","version":2,"serverId":"e7caa4g8-7642-45f5-abc9-c9f3ad325274","pl' at line 1
```

I created my database like this:

```
create table websocket_test
(
  output json null
);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: You can't just stuff values into your query, you **must** [use placeholder values](http://bobby-tables.com/python).

Comment: Imagine what would happen if `data` contained `''); drop table users;`. That's how SQL Injection attacks happen